# New Column based on aggregation from different df with specific conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, aggregate

I have two data frames:

- `df1` includes rows with a date
- `df2` includes rows with type and date

I would like to create column `"b"` in `df1`, that is a list of all types (including duplicates) of `df2` with `df2.date` less then `df1.date`

Example:

- `df1` has a row with date `2023-01-01`
- `df2` has three rows:

  - one of type AAA with date `2022-01-01`
  - second of type AAA with date `2022-01-02`
  - third of type BBB with date `2023-02-02`
- result is `['AAA','AAA']`

Comment: Please provide us a minimal data sample that we can copy/paste. Also consider reviewing [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

def gen(n):
    t0 = pd.Timestamp('2000')
    t1 = (t0 + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 6000, n), unit='D'))
    t2 = (t0 + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 6000, n), unit='D'))
    type_ = [x*3 for x in np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), n)]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': t1})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': t2, 'type': type_})
    return df1, df2
```

Example:

```py
np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible example
df1, df2 = gen(8)

>>> df1
        date
0 2007-06-25
1 2007-02-20
2 2004-07-11
3 2008-12-08
4 2013-07-02
5 2013-04-21
6 2015-12-15
7 2002-10-30

>>> df2
        date type
0 2011-12-22  YYY
1 2016-01-31  RRR
2 2016-03-21  FFF
3 2009-06-30  ZZZ
4 2001-12-06  NNN
5 2007-02-12  III
6 2005-11-05  JJJ
7 2006-01-31  UUU
```

Then, we concat the two `df`s, sort by date, and calculate a "cumulative list" of `'type'` (dropping the `NaN` that come from `df1`). Also, note the added index lavel `'k'`, which will allow us very quickly to retrieve the rows from `df1`.

```py
def as_list(s):
    # empty list for NaN
    return [s] if s == s else []

z = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[0, 1], names=['k']).sort_values(['date', 'k'])
cumlist = z['type'].apply(as_list).cumsum()
newdf1 = df1.assign(b=cumlist.loc[0])

>>> newdf1
        date                               b
0 2007-06-25            [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III]
1 2007-02-20            [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III]
2 2004-07-11                           [NNN]
3 2008-12-08            [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III]
4 2013-07-02  [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY]
5 2013-04-21  [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY]
6 2015-12-15  [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY]
7 2002-10-30                           [NNN]
```

#### Explanation

Let's look at the content of `z` above:

```py
>>> z
          date type
k                  
1 4 2001-12-06  NNN
0 7 2002-10-30  NaN
  2 2004-07-11  NaN
1 6 2005-11-05  JJJ
  7 2006-01-31  UUU
..         ...  ...
0 5 2013-04-21  NaN
  4 2013-07-02  NaN
  6 2015-12-15  NaN
1 1 2016-01-31  RRR
  2 2016-03-21  FFF
```

It contains the `type` from `df2`, and `NaN` for the `df1` rows. It also has `k==0` level-0 index for `df1` rows. It is sorted by `date`, and also by `k` (to break the ties if any date is present in both dfs: enforce rows from `df1` to come first, as we want `type`s from `df2` for dates *before* the dates in `df1`).

Then, let's look at `cumlist`:

```py
>>> cumlist
k   
1  4                                       [NNN]
0  7                                       [NNN]
   2                                       [NNN]
1  6                                  [NNN, JJJ]
   7                             [NNN, JJJ, UUU]
                          ...                   
0  5              [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY]
   4              [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY]
   6              [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY]
1  1         [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY, RRR]
   2    [NNN, JJJ, UUU, III, ZZZ, YYY, RRR, FFF]
```

For `k==0`, these are the lists we want.

#### Addendum: new 'ID' columns

Say both DataFrames also have an `ID` column, and we want to perform the same operation as above, but separately for each `ID`.

The solution becomes:

```py
z = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[0, 1], names=['k']).sort_values(['ID', 'date', 'k'])
cumlist = z.assign(
    type=z['type'].apply(as_list)
).groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['type'].apply(pd.Series.cumsum)
newdf1 = df1.assign(b=cumlist.loc[0])
```

Example:

```py
def gen(n, n_id=4):
    t0 = pd.Timestamp('2000')
    t1 = (t0 + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 6000, n), unit='D'))
    t2 = (t0 + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 6000, n), unit='D'))
    type_ = [x*3 for x in np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), n)]
    ids = np.repeat(np.arange(n_id), n // n_id + 1)[:n]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': t1, 'ID': ids})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': t2, 'ID': ids, 'type': type_})
    return df1, df2

np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible example
df1, df2 = gen(8, 2)

# code above to get newdf1

>>> newdf1
        date  ID                b
0 2007-06-25   0            [NNN]
1 2007-02-20   0            [NNN]
2 2004-07-11   0            [NNN]
3 2008-12-08   0            [NNN]
4 2013-07-02   0  [NNN, ZZZ, YYY]
5 2013-04-21   1  [JJJ, UUU, III]
6 2015-12-15   1  [JJJ, UUU, III]
7 2002-10-30   1               []
```

Comment: What adjustment would i need to do, if i want to do the same but with multiple persons (identities), in the form of ID  in df1 and df2?

Comment: That would most likely be the same logic, but in a `groupby('ID')`. I'd have to see some sample data and think about it.

Comment: I have tried some things but with no luck. I would appreciate an solution if you can. The data can be the same as the one you built, just with an ID column in both tables. Can open a new thread if needed

Comment: Please see addendum in the answer.